# react-animarker highlight not updating with state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have some text that I want to simply highlight using a simple react package called 'react-animarker'. I have tried to use useState hook as I want to dynamically update the speed of the animation as shown. However, the duration does not change the way I want it to. But in the console, it does show as changing. Any ideas as to why?

Link to React Package: https://github.com/ramonmetzker/react-animarker

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import {Mark} from 'react-animarker'


const Highlightx = () => {

    const [speed, setSpeed] = useState(5)

    const handleClick = () => {
        setSpeed(20)
        console.log(speed);
    }  

  return (
    <>
    <Mark duration={speed}>Highlightx</Mark>
    <button onClick={handleClick}>Hello</button>
    </>
  )
}

export default Highlightx
```

Comment: By any chance, do you mean the other way around? The changed `speed` is passed down properly, but the `console.log` shows the original speed?

Comment: I had the same question as @CertainPerformance.  Using the state value directly after setting it will not show up until the next render, therefore the speed value output on the console.log will be the value of the *current* render - before you set the speed to 20.

Comment: No, the first time I click, the console shows the original value, but then since the second click it updates properly. It's just the actual highlighter that never updates.

Comment: The highlighter itself never resets and starts again after clicking the button. It just continues at the original pace.

Comment: Your react code looks alright for changing state .  I'm not familiar enough with react-animarker to know if changing properties of <Mark> will change the state of the highlight.

Comment: @ckesplin Would you be knowing any other plugin or method to progressively highlight text that I could implement in react? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: if you try `const handleClick = () => setSpeed(prev => prev + 20)`, would speed change noticely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After taking a look at the library you are using, I found a solution:

For some reason, React does not see any state change with the `<Mark>` component when the `duration` property changes, therefore, React does not force a refresh of the component.  If you add a `key` property that changes with the duration, then it will force a re-render of the Mark component and re-draw your highlight.

ex:

```js
<Mark key={speed} duration={speed}>
```

Here is simple example in codesandbox (simply change the value of the input field and the highlight will re-draw after each change): [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-animarker-with-state-change-g6kjoe)